# Drupal reports "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later"

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

When I login to the backend of my site and I click either the content tab or the people tab I get the error "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later". I have not altered any core code on the site just the frontend theme. My thinking is that Drupal needs updating to the latest version as it is currently on 8.2.5 and some of the plugins are not up-to-date.

I tried updating Drupal and the site crashed, I have also updated a couple of modules but 2 of them wouldn't update and they were: https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag or https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_extender.

Here is the PHP error message:

```
TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Drupal\views\Entity\Render\EntityFieldRenderer::render() must be an instance of Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\Field, instance of Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\EntityField given, called in /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/field/EntityField.php on line 809 in Drupal\views\Entity\Render\EntityFieldRenderer->render() (line 120 of /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/modules/views/src/Entity/Render/EntityFieldRenderer.php) 

#0 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/field/EntityField.php(809): Drupal\views\Entity\Render\EntityFieldRenderer->render(Object(Drupal\views\ResultRow), Object(Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\EntityField)) 
#1 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/field/FieldPluginBase.php(1137): Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\EntityField->getItems(Object(Drupal\views\ResultRow)) 
#2 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/modules/views/views.theme.inc(224): Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\FieldPluginBase->advancedRender(Object(Drupal\views\ResultRow)) 
#3 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Theme/ThemeManager.php(287): template_preprocess_views_view_field(Array, 'views_view_fiel...', Array) 
#4 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(435): Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('views_view_fiel...', Array) 
#5 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(195): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, false) 
#6 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/field/FieldPluginBase.php(1736): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) 
#7 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/style/StylePluginBase.php(765): Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\FieldPluginBase->theme(Object(Drupal\views\ResultRow)) 
#8 [internal function]: Drupal\views\Plugin\views\style\StylePluginBase->elementPreRenderRow(Array) 
#9 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(376): call_user_func(Array, Array) 
#10 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(195): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, false) 
#11 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/style/StylePluginBase.php(713): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) 
#12 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/style/StylePluginBase.php(580): Drupal\views\Plugin\views\style\StylePluginBase->renderFields(Array) 
#13 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/style/StylePluginBase.php(466): Drupal\views\Plugin\views\style\StylePluginBase->renderGrouping(Array, Array, true) 
#14 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/display/DisplayPluginBase.php(2117): Drupal\views\Plugin\views\style\StylePluginBase->render(Array) 
#15 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/modules/views/src/ViewExecutable.php(1520): Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\DisplayPluginBase->render() 
#16 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/display/Page.php(171): Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->render() 
#17 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/modules/views/src/ViewExecutable.php(1617): Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\Page->execute() 
#18 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/modules/views/src/Element/View.php(78): Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->executeDisplay('page_1', Array) 
#19 [internal function]: Drupal\views\Element\View::preRenderViewElement(Array) 
#20 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(376): call_user_func(Array, Array) 
#21 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(195): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, false) 
#22 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/MainContent/HtmlRenderer.php(226): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, false) 
#23 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(574): Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\{closure}() 
#24 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/MainContent/HtmlRenderer.php(227): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object(Drupal\Core\Render\RenderContext), Object(Closure)) 
#25 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/MainContent/HtmlRenderer.php(117): Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->prepare(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), Object(Drupal\Core\Routing\CurrentRouteMatch)) 
#26 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/MainContentViewSubscriber.php(90): Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), Object(Drupal\Core\Routing\CurrentRouteMatch)) 
#27 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/lib/Drupal/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php(111): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForControllerResultEvent), 'kernel.view', Object(Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher)) 
#28 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(144): Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.view', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForControllerResultEvent)) 
#29 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(62): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1) 
#30 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php(57): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) 
#31 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php(47): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) 
#32 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(99): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) 
#33 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(78): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) 
#34 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php(47): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) 
#35 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php(50): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) 
#36 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) 
#37 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(652): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) 
#38 /srv/bindings/786d3e8414d9428c9683501ffa37adf3/code/index.php(19): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) 
#39 {main}.
```

Comment: Forgot to add in the title this is Drupal 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have issue with Drupal core updates.

> The problem is this:
>
> `Argument 2 passed to Drupal\views\Entity\Render\EntityFieldRenderer::render() must be an instance of Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\Field, instance of Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\EntityField given`
>
> That plugin got renamed from Field to EntityField. See [#2408667: Rename Field.php to EntityField.php](https://www.drupal.org/node/2408667). But that only got committed to 8.3.x, so something seems to have gone wrong during your update to 8.2.5. Some shuffling between 8.3 and 8.2? Can you try running the update again?

Take a look here for details: https://www.drupal.org/node/2848227

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I will contact my hosting company to see if they can assist me in trying to update Drupal and will let you know how I get on.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you :)